# SagePay - An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, transactions, httpwebrequest, integration, opayo

Following the instructions at: [The SagePay Documentation](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=buxdjpRBiyWKQ_Ky_TFWSKdtCJ1sdzbs_A0UGgm29d8)

I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

1. create the URL to POST containing all required values (VPSProtocol,TxType,Vendor, Crypt)
2. Encrypt the Crypt field (containing all required values) using Form Integration Encryption Password as Key and IV (RijndaelManaged)
3. Instantiate HttpWebRequest (KeepAlive = false; Method = "POST" (also tried GET))
4. SecurityProtocol = Tls12 (also tried Ssl3 and Tls)
5. Initially my calling site is not Https (no SSL Certificate)
6. Tried creating a Self-Signed Certificate
7. The Encryption process uses MemoryStream/CryptoStream/StreamWriter to encrypt the data to be passed in the Crypt param
8. The url replicates Apendix A Crypt Field Example
9. Sagepay Url - https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp which I am appending the params to.

Response

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

```
string valsToCrypt = "VendorTxCode= ....etc

using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    var passToBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pass val");
    myRijndael.Key = passToBytes;
    myRijndael.IV = passToBytes;

    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. 
    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(valsToCrypt, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

    string cryptEncrypted = "";

    foreach (byte item in encrypted)
    {
        cryptEncrypted += item;
    }

    string uri = "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp";
    uri += "?VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=vendorname&Crypt=@" + cryptEncrypted;
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
```

Pretty much running out of ideas.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Its impossible to debug without seeing it. Please give us a [mcve]

Comment: Well looks like there is a dearth of knowledge on SagePay/.net but, thankfully, I may have discovered the issue.    I created a console application using the exact same code and it worked, using .net 4.0 framework whereas the web app uses .net 4.5. The console app was run from my local desktop whereas the app was run from a Windows web server. Strong suggestion that the issue is with SagePay/.net 4.5. The proof will be when I build the web app in .net 4.0 and see what happens.

Comment: Well the error you are getting is form your code, not theirs. The documentation is pretty clear on how to send and receive to their servers, I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: As I indicated in a comment, the exact same code works through a console app running from my desktop. Note: "the exact same code". Therefore the issue is probably with either with the framework/sagepay or the server.

Comment: I've removed a few comments here; please keep the comments on topic and constructive.